# Simplified Heat Transfer from Boiling water into pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am trying to find the heat transfer from boiling water into a pipe of cold water running through a boiler. It has been forever since I took thermodynamics and i'm a bit confused.

I have a model for finding the heat transfer through the walls of the pipe using the thermal resistance method and there are a bunch of examples with heat transfer to flowing water so I think I am good on that front.

My question is.... How do I find a **Heat transfer value from the boiling water to the surface of the pipe**. I have included a simple diagram below. [image]

There are two methods I have found that I think have lead to my confusion.

First, there is the heat transfer equation:

q = mc(T2-T1)

If we were to use this equation, would the m be the mass of the boiling water? or would you turn it into a mass flow rate problem and use the mass flow rate of the water running through the pipe? Since there are 3 different temperatures in this system (the temperature of the boiling water, the cold water entering the pipe and the hotter water exiting the pipe) I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

The second way to find this (I think) is:

q = h2- h1

using the enthalpys of the water at different temperatures. Again, I do not think this is the correct method since it seems....too simple.

There are a lot of heat exchanger example problems out there. HOWEVER they all seem to know the heat transfer rate *or* they are assuming a *counter or parallel flow* heat exchanger.

Since only one of the fluids is moving in this heat exchanger, trying to figure out what information to use has been tricky.

There is probably something I am assuming or thinking about wrong so if anyone could help out that would be awesome! Thanks!!

Comment: Questions like this are better for Engineering Stack Exchange FYI

Comment: Boiling water is not flowing?  If the answer is "yes", how is the boiling water kept hot enough to boil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *know* the entry $T_1$ and exit $T_2$ temperatures of the colder fluid, then the calculation is easy.  The heat transferred to the colder fluid is nearly the equation you had:

$$Q=\dot m c_p (T_2-T_1) $$

where the heat transfer rate $Q$ (e.g. Watts) is a product of the temperature change times the mass flow rate $\dot m$ (e.g. in kg/s) and the specific heat of $c_p$ of the colder fluid (e.g. in J/(kg-K)).  You may have to compensate for $c_p$ increasing with temperature if the temperature rise is great.

If you do not know the exit temperature or need to find how $T_2$ varies for different flow rates or boiler temperatures, that is a more advanced problem. The equation typically used is some form of:

$$Q=UA\Delta T_{lm}$$

Where $UA$ is the overall heat transfer coefficient $[\rm {J/(m}^2 \rm {K)]}$ times the overall surface area $A$ and  $\Delta T_{lm}$ is the Log Mean Temp Difference, which is a function of the inlet and exit temps of both hot and cold streams. These are parameters you could perhaps estimate from Heat Exchanger literature for your system's parameters.

Comment: Awesome! This makes sense, thank you so much! Also I did not know engineering stack exchange was a thing, might get lost in there later today.